# Disable dark mode laravel breeze package

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-livewire, darkmode, laravel-breeze

Good evening dear colleagues, I hope you are well, I need your help, I would like to deactivate the dark mode of the Laravel breeze package for all types of browsers (Chrome, Safari...). My need is to force the "Light" mode of laravel breeze. I hope you can help me solve my problem.

I already added the darkMode:'media' line in the tailwind.config.js file but it didn't work